# Three.js raycasting object selection with animation

Tags: javascript, three.js

Raycasting selection is working fine for my project on static meshes, however for animated meshes the ray selection doesn't seem to see the movement of the mesh and only responds to the mesh's non-animated (original) position.

My selection code is as follows:

```
element.addEventListener( 'mouseup', function ( event ) 
{

  var vector = new THREE.Vector3(( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1, -( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1, 0.5);
  vector = vector.unproject(camera);
  var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position, vector.sub(camera.position).normalize());
  var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(pickable_objects, true);

  if (intersects.length > 0) 
  {
      //I change the object's material colour so that I can see the selection
  }
}
```

Where `pickable_objects` is an array of three.js mesh objects that are selectable, these do not carry animation information as far as I am aware, so the result I'm complaining about may not be surprising to some.

I haven't included the colour changing code or the JSON mesh reader code here as I don't believe it's pertinent.

So with static meshes the ray casting is very accurate, but for animated meshes I have to click in the very centre of the object or find its original non-animated position to make the selection work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the source code in the github repo, particularly [Raycaster.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/core/Raycaster.js), you'll see that the actual implementation is in the geometry object. For instance [Mesh.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/objects/Mesh.js) implements the raycast by iterating over its triangles and checking whether the ray intersects any of them but [SkinnedMesh.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/objects/SkinnedMesh.js) does not override this method.

Finally, a quick search in the issues page showed that this is actually a known limitation - https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/6440.

You seem to be left with 2 options - bump the issue in github and ask for an ETA or implement this yourself (and send a pull request afterwards hopefully).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is quite annoying, I'll check out the source and nip over to the git page.

Comment: Update: raycasting for skinned meshes was added in https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/19178 - r116